# Decipher name of Reverend on Burial entry

Tags: palaeography, 1930s, burial-records, wiltshire

This is a snippet from a burial entry. I am not permitted to show the full image:

[image]

I am trying to decipher the name of the Reverend. I think it is: **Rev. A. E. Markly**.

This was in 1933 in Salisbury at the London Road Cemetery, Salisbury.

I tried to find a history of Reverends or even a map of the site ... to no avail.

---

## Side Note

Not related to the name deciphering, but I did find a webpage about the [London Road Cemetery](https://www.salisburycitycouncil.gov.uk/l/london-road-cemetery) where it has a link to a [map](https://www.salisburycitycouncil.gov.uk/images/pdf/cemeteries/London_Road_Cemetery_Map.pdf) in PDF. It gives a basic overview of the site. On that page it also says:

> There is a detailed map at the entrance to the Cemetery on the left.

Comment: I think it could be Markby

Comment: It's probably also worth checking (post-Covid) whether any local libraries have historic copies of *Crockford's Clerical Directory* That's an annual list of Anglican clergy, first published in 1858 and still being published today.  [Lambeth Palace Library](https://www.lambethpalacelibrary.org/sites/default/files/clerical_directories.pdf) has an almost complete set of volumes (including 1932, 1933, and 1934), but other libraries near you may have volumes from around 1933.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree with the comments that it more likely reads "C. E. Markby".

A good possibility would be the Rev. Cecil Edward Campbell Markby. He was recorded as "Clerk of Holy Orders" in Dorchester, Dorset on the 1939 Register, a short way from Salisbury (see RG 101/6918C, no 187):

[image]

Local newspapers seem to confirm this is the right man. For example, in the [*Bath Chronicle*, 17 June 1933](https://www.britishnewspaperarchive.co.uk/search/results/1930-01-01/1939-12-31?basicsearch=markby%20salisbury&somesearch=markby%20salisbury&exactsearch=false&retrievecountrycounts=false):

> Mr. C. E. C. Markby, B.A., Emmanuel College, Cambridge, who was ordained priest at Salisbury Cathedral on Sunday, is a son of the Rev. A. W. Markby, Vicar of St. Peter's, Dorchester, and formerly St. Saviour's, Bath...